# How to split functions into another file in index.js

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I would like to split functions to different js files, using webhook hosted in firebase.

Because i anticipate i will be writing more functions int the future.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

  function hello(agent) {
      console.log("hello);
  }


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('hello',hello);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const  welcome  = require('./welcome')
const  fallback  = require('./fallback')

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

You can split files like `welcome`, `fallback`

=> **welcome.js**

```
const welcome = (agent) => {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
}
module.exports = welcome
```

=> **fallback.js**

```
const fallback = (agent) => {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}
module.exports  =  fallback
```